# Is there anyway I can recover and use a 128GB flash drive that seems to be damaged? I don’t need the data on it but want to use it

Tags: usb, windows-11

I have a 128GB USB flash drive that I found on my desk. It has been there for about 3-4 months, maybe longer? I left it there because it wasn't working at the time. Explorer doesn't recognize it as a drive, but it shows up as "Flash Drive" on the taskbar. When I click on it, it shows this:

[image: Image of what Settings shows]

After a bit, it turns into this:

[image: Other image of what Settings shows]

I think I dropped it too much. Anyway, it was around $40 and I don't want to have to buy a whole new USB flash drive.

Comment: I assume you don’t need to recover data, thus my adjusting the title to clarify that you want to simply use the drive. That is the issue correct?

Comment: Yes, that is what is happening. I don't really care what was on it, but it would be nice to have it.

Comment: You want to use a drive which you know is damaged?

Comment: You dropped the flash drive and now you're looking for a software solution to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not practically.

The message is telling you the drives controller is working, but the actual storage is stuffed.

Its possible that the drive could be repaired by someone with the skill to do so, but its likely to cost more then the value of the drive.

I've not tried it, but there is an outside chance that removing the pcb from its housing and baking it at 120c for a few hours could fix it... or kill it better.

Comment: At this point I'll do just about anything. How would I do that?

Comment: Its not a great idea, but turn iven on to 120c/250f, open pen drive and remove PCB. Put PCB in oven for 5 hours, with the side having most components up.  Allow to cool.  If that does not work, try following https://bikehike.org/how-long-bake-to-bake-pcb-for-repair/ - ie put in at 100c, gradually heat to 220c. Remove after a couple of mins at 220c.

Comment: Thanks! How do you remove a PCB?

Comment: That depends totally on the particular memory stick you have and there is no single solution - you would need to work it out yourself, or maybe google it.  If you are embarking on this project for any reason other then to learn you are wasting your time.